# Can't add foreign keys because unique constraint needed

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm brand new to using Oracle SQLDeveloper and I'm working on a college project right now. I keep trying to add foreign key constraints to my tables(which already hold the foreign key as an attribute) so Im using ALTER like this:

```
alter table applies
add constraint e_number foreign key (e_number)
references student (e_number);
```

where `e_number` is the primary key in a table called `student`. The student table's `e_number` has the primary key constraint and also has an index that was auto-generated where it says UNIQUE under the UNIQUENESS column in the indexes tab. Whenever I try and create a foreign key for any of my tables I'm getting this same error everytime:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
alter table applies
add constraint e_number foreign key (e_number)
references student (e_number)
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-02264: name already used by an existing constraint
02264. 00000 -  "name already used by an existing constraint"
*Cause:    The specified constraint name has to be unique.
*Action:   Specify a unique constraint name for the constraint.
```

I'm a bit confused and have been reading about unique on several sites but still don't get it. When I call an ALTER I can either specify a FOREIGN key or specify a UNIQUE key. Am I supposed to ALTER unique and then ALTER foreign? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try another name for the constraint, if I remember correctly, it needs to be unique not only for the table but for the entire schema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you already have a key named e_number. Try:

```
alter table applies
add constraint applies_student_e_number foreign key (e_number)
references student (e_number);
```

Comment: Yes this is what I've been doing. I've been adding different prefixes like "blah_" before it, but is this the right way? Is it not supposed to just have the same name? .. and still be fk

Comment: `references table(column)` must match the referenced table/column names. The names of keys created with `add constraint you_can_name_this_whatever_you_want` must be unique within the db. In your case, since student's primary key is named `e_number`, you need a different name for the `applies.e_number` foreign key.